# How to capture Tomcat startup log

Tags: tomcat, logging, startup

How to capture Tomcat startup log?

Comment: can you please add more details to your question

Comment: You can find instructions from here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html and here: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging

Answer (score 8):

To start Tomcat in Windows, you can execute command:

> catalina run

in your 'tomcat\bin' folder. Output from Tomcat startup will stay in current window, so you can analyze it.

Answer (score 1):

The Tomcat startup log is already captured as catalina.out in Unix and in catalina.log on Windows.

Comment: The startup output from Tomcat is definitely not logged in catalina.log.  Maybe something has changed, but Tomcat 7 spews thousands of lines of output, including exceptions to the screen and doesn't capture them in any log file.

Comment: You are right. I'm seeing the same thing. I'm getting an error running Tomcat 7 but I can't see the whole output.

Answer (score 0):

On newer Versions Start-Up-Logfiles are under `>Tomcat-Root<\logs\catalina.>date<.txt`.