# Difference between different Tomcat log types and How should these logs be investigated for trouble shooting

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

**Background:**

I recently have some trouble with one of my http website deployed on tomcat 8, when trying to figure out what is happenning, I see different log files in the `/logs` directory:

```
catalina.out
catalina.2018-12-12.log
commons-daemon.2018-12-12.log
localhost.2018-12-12.log
localhost_access_log.2018-12-12.txt
tomcat7-stderr.2018-12-12.log
tomcat7-stdout.2018-12-12.log
```

**What I have got:**

I know that different logs come from different configurations, but that is not what I care about. Also I found [Tomcat 7 log files differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963820/tomcat-7-log-files-differences) , but it does not answer my questions fully.
I also have some ideas of my own, but I would like to learn from others.

**My questions:**

1. Is these logs enough for trouble shooting? if not, please add required log types and how to create them(according to some cofigurations).
2. If they are enough, What's the difference between them, and, most importanly, how should I read them? I should have some kind of log reading order(or, priority), since I think that different log types can provide dirrerent aspects  to us for trouble shooting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859365/how-to-capture-tomcat-startup-log startup log